# Object does not match target type with WinRT XAML Toolkit Chart

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

As stated in the title, I've got this exception when I try to use the *WinRT XAML Toolkit*'s chart.

Here's a quick snippet of my code:

```
public ObservableDictionary<string, int> MyDict { get; set; }
...
<Charting:Chart Grid.Row="2"
                Margin="0">
     <Charting:Chart.Series>
         <Charting:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding MyDict}"
                              IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Key}"
                              DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"/>
    </Charting:Chart.Series>
</Charting:Chart>
```

I can't find anything useful online and I really don't want to be forced to write a new class that wraps the two items in order to bind to a `List` because it's quite nonsense.

Any idea?

Comment: Is this only happening in the designer or while running as well? Does the page work if you remove the chart? Are you setting MyDict before the binding occurs? Maybe a null value is being returned?

Comment: This happens while running the app, and changing the `Dictionary` to a `List` make everything work but, as stated in the question, this is nonsense. `Dictionary`'s purpose is to map things together, being forced to create a wrapper class to use it inside a `List` means that something has not be designed in a proper way

Comment: I wonder if there is something wrong with your ObservableDictionary implementation, or if something changes when you implement it with a List.

Comment: I'm using the `ObservableDictionary` that is found in the `Common` folder in each Windows Universal project. I don't know if this has some problems, but I don't think MS would include bugged code in the default project

Comment: Probably not. Then, could you post the code that you use for initializing MyDict and the list implementation?